# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen when installing Homebrew on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I've started getting weird errors on MacOS 10.13.3 (17D102).

I've just tried to install Homebrew using the instructions on the [GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/install) page and received this error:

```
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Counting objects: 4680, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4476/4476), done.
remote: Total 4680 (delta 45), reused 694 (delta 19), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (4680/4680), 3.81 MiB | 4.74 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (45/45), done.
Tapped 4478 formulae (4,722 files, 11.9MB)
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/github_api_headers20180308-4136-cqt2yb
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core
```

I have tried:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

As per [this guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228) and still receive the error.

Running `Brew Doctor` returns `Your system is ready to brew.` and my Ruby Version is `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin16.6.0]`

The error can be more easily repeatable using `brew install zsh`.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/426

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i had sudo'd to the postgres user.
Exiting back to my normal user allowed me to proceed without obstacle.